# python querying all rows of azure table

Tags: python, azure, azure-table-storage

I have around  20000 rows in my azure table . I wanted to query all the rows in the azure table . But due to certain azure limitation i am getting only 1000 rows.

**My code**

```
from azure.storage import TableService
table_service = TableService(account_name='xxx', account_key='YYY')
i=0
tasks=table_service.query_entities('ValidOutputTable',"PartitionKey eq 'tasksSeattle'")
for task in tasks:
    i+=1
    print task.RowKey,task.DomainUrl,task.Status    
print i
```

I want to get all the rows from the validoutputtable .Is there a way to do so

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> But due to certain azure limitation i am getting only 1000 rows.

This is a documented limitation. Each query request to Azure Table will return no more than 1000 rows. If there are more than 1000 entities, table service will return a continuation token that must be used to fetch next set of entities (See Remarks section here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179421.aspx)

Please see the sample code to fetch all entities from a table:

```
from azure import *
from azure.storage import TableService

table_service = TableService(account_name='xxx', account_key='yyy')
i=0
next_pk = None
next_rk = None
while True:
    entities=table_service.query_entities('Address',"PartitionKey eq 'Address'", next_partition_key = next_pk, next_row_key = next_rk, top=1000)
    i+=1
    for entity in entities:
        print(entity.AddressLine1)
    if hasattr(entities, 'x_ms_continuation'):
        x_ms_continuation = getattr(entities, 'x_ms_continuation')
        next_pk = x_ms_continuation['nextpartitionkey']
        next_rk = x_ms_continuation['nextrowkey']
    else:
        break;
```

Answer (score 6):

### Update 2019

Just running for loop on the query result (as author of the topic does) - will get all the data from the query.

```py
from azure.cosmosdb.table.tableservice import TableService

table_service = TableService(account_name='accont_name', account_key='key')

#counter to keep track of records
counter=0

# get the rows. Debugger shows the object has only 100 records
rows = table_service.query_entities(table,"PartitionKey eq 'mykey'")

for row in rows:
    if (counter%100 == 0):
        # just to keep output smaller, print every 100 records
        print("Processing {} record".format(counter))
    counter+=1
```

The output proves that loop goes over a 1000 records

```
...
Processing 363500 record
Processing 363600 record
...
```

Answer (score 6):

Azure Table Storage has a new python library in preview release that is available for installation via pip. To install use the following pip command

```
pip install azure-data-tables
```

To query all rows for a given table with the newest library, you can use the following code snippet:

```py
from azure.data.tables import TableClient

key = os.environ['TABLES_PRIMARY_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY']
account_name = os.environ['tables_storage_account_name']
endpoint = os.environ['TABLES_STORAGE_ENDPOINT_SUFFIX']
account_url = "{}.table.{}".format(account_name, endpoint)
table_name = "myBigTable"

with TableClient(account_url=account_url, credential=key, table_name=table_name) as table_client:

    try:
        table_client.create_table()
    except:
        pass

    i = 0
    for entity in table_client.list_entities():
        print(entity['value'])
        i += 1
        if i % 100 == 0:
            print(i)
```

Your outlook would look like this: (modified for brevity, assuming there are 2000 entities)

```
...
1100
1200
1300
...
```

Comment: There should be a special award for updating answers to the latest code.  Thank you!