# Conflict accessing twice in azure storage table simultaneously

Tags: python, azure, azure-storage

I've been running a script to retrieve data from an Azure storage table (such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019437/python-querying-all-rows-of-azure-table) one as a reference) and copy it in another table from the same storage account without problem.

Now, the issue came when I tried to access this latter table to run some calculations and copy that in another table from the same storage account. This script returned the following error:

```
AzureConflictHttpError: Conflict
{"odata.error":{"code":"EntityAlreadyExists","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The specified entity already exists.\nRequestId:57d9b721-6002-012d-3d0c-b88bef000000\nTime:2019-01-29T19:55:53.5984026Z"}}}
```

At the same time, however, the code I was running previously also stopped printing the same error and won't start again even if no code is run, returning the previous error over and over again.

Is there any way to access the same API in azure storage multiple times?

UPDATE

Adding the source code, sorry for not having done that before. Basically the 2 codes I'm running in parallel are the same but with different filters; on this one I'm taking the data from Table 1 (which has a row per second) and I'm averaging these numbers per minute to add a row to Table 2, and on the other script I'm taking data from this Table 2 to average these rows per minute to a 5-minute average row in another Table 3, so basically a few parameters change but the code is basically the same.

There will be a third script, slightly different to these 2, but will take Table 2 as the input source, run other calculations and paste the results in a new row per minute in a future Table 4, so in general my idea is to have multiple entries to multiple tables at the same time to build new specific tables.

```
import datetime
import time
from azure.storage.table import TableService, Entity

delta_time = '00:01:00'
retrieve_time = '00:10:00'
start_time = '08:02:00'
utc_diff = 3

table_service = TableService(account_name='xxx', account_key='yyy')

while True:
    now_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S") 
    now_date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
    hour = datetime.datetime.now().hour

    if hour >= 21:
        now_date = (datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)).strftime("%d-%m-%Y")

    retrieve_max = (datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(hours=utc_diff)+ datetime.timedelta(minutes=-10)).strftime("%H:%M:%S")

    start_diff = datetime.datetime.strptime(now_time, '%H:%M:%S') - datetime.datetime.strptime(start_time, '%H:%M:%S') + datetime.timedelta(hours=utc_diff)
    if start_diff.total_seconds() > 0:

        query = "PartitionKey eq '"+str(now_date)+"' and RowKey ge '"+str(retrieve_max)+"'"
        tasks=table_service.query_entities('Table1',query)
        iqf_0 = []

        for task in tasks:
            if task.Name == "IQF_0":
                iqf_0.append([task.RowKey, task.Area])  

        last_time = iqf_0[len(iqf_0)-1][0]
        time_max = datetime.datetime.strptime(last_time, '%H:%M:%S') - datetime.datetime.strptime(delta_time, '%H:%M:%S') #+ datetime.timedelta(hours=utc_diff)
        area = 0.0
        count = 0
        for i in range(len(iqf_0)-1, -1, -1):
            diff = datetime.datetime.strptime(last_time, '%H:%M:%S') - datetime.datetime.strptime(iqf_0[i][0], '%H:%M:%S')
            if diff.total_seconds() < 60:
                area += iqf_0[i][1]
                count += 1
            else: 
                break
        area_average = area/count

        output_row = Entity()
        output_row.PartitionKey = now_date
        output_row.RowKey = last_time
        output_row.Name = task.Name
        output_row.Area = area_average
        table_service.insert_entity('Table2', output_row)

        date_max = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=-1)
        date_max = date_max.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
        query = "PartitionKey eq '"+str(date_max)+"' and RowKey ge '"+str(retrieve_max)+"'"
        tasks=table_service.query_entities('Table2',query)

        for task in tasks:
            diff = datetime.datetime.strptime(now_time, '%H:%M:%S') - datetime.datetime.strptime(task.RowKey, '%H:%M:%S') + datetime.timedelta(hours=utc_diff)
            print(i, datetime.datetime.strptime(now_time, '%H:%M:%S'), datetime.datetime.strptime(task.RowKey, '%H:%M:%S'), diff.total_seconds())
            if task.PartitionKey == date_max and diff.total_seconds()>0:
                table_service.delete_entity('Table2', task.PartitionKey, task.RowKey)

        time.sleep(60 - time.time() % 60)
```

Comment: Could you please share more details of your scenario? For example, are you accessing 3 tables from 2 applications? How do your application read and write the 3 tables (especially how the partition keys are row keys are organized)? If possible, could you share your source code so that we can understand your question better?

Comment: Hi @ZhaoxingLu-Microsoft, just added the code and more details. PartitionKey are basically the days in "dd-mm-yyyy" format and RowKeys the Hour in "hh:mm:ss" format. My intention is to reduce the amount of lines from Table 1 to Table 2 (averaging 60 rows from T1 to 1 row in T2), and the same operation from Table 2 to Table 3 (averaging 5 rows from T2 to 1 row in T3).

Comment: I didn't read the code carefully since the time conversion logic is quite complex and hard to understand. Have you tried to run the first script alone and see if the error can still happen? I suspect that the while loop in a single script resulted in the `EntityAlreadyExists` error, because the loop inserts entities with the same **partition key** and **row key** for more than one time. I'd suggest you to write a log to display **partition key** and **row key** before inserting the entity to table, that may help you find the culprit.

Comment: I've run the first code again and works fine, maybe it wasn't working right after the conflict due to some info cached. So you're saying that the same partitionkey and rowkey can't be duplicated in different tables from the same account? I'll get the log and update the post, thanks!

Comment: No, the same partition key and row key can't be duplicated in the same table, but it's fine across different tables. However, since you were seeing EntityAlreadyExists error, it means your code did try to insert entities with the same partition key and row key into the same table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you were running two codes to copy data in a same Azure Storage Accout from Table 1 to Table 2 to Table 3 at the same time. Per my experience, the issue was normally caused by writing a data record (a Table Entity) concurrently at the same time, or using the incorrect method for an existing Entity, which is resource competition issue for writing.

It's a common Table Service Error, you can find it at [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/table-service-error-codes).
[image]

And there is a document [`Inserting and Updating Entities`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/inserting-and-updating-entities) which explains the differences of the operation effect between the functions `Insert Entity`, `Update Entity`, `Merge Entity`, `Insert Or Merge Entity`, and `Insert Or Replace Entity`.

Now, your code did not shared for us. Considering for all possible cases, there are three solutions to fix the issue.

1. Run your two codes one after another in order of copying data between different tables, not concurrently.
2. Using the correct function to update data for an existing entity, you can refer to the document above and the similar SO thread [Add or replace entity in Azure Table Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466764/add-or-replace-entity-in-azure-table-storage).
3. To use a global lock for a unique primary key of a Table Entity to avoid operating the same Table Entity concurrently in two codes at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Peter Pan, just added the code and a few more comments, but basically my problem is what you mention in your first lines (I'm using the same Table Entity). Should this be an update of the table entity then? But how, since I'm adding more new lines every 1 and 5 minutes respectively? Regarding your solutions the first one can't be possible since my is to keep these scripts running permanently to build these tables on the go, I'll do some research on the latter 2. Thanks!